# Generation of an HTML div based table with column header spanning several (but not all) cells

Tags: html, xslt-1.0

Given a XML like this fragment (which will be generated), I need to generate a web page using div entries, based on XSLT 1.0, which looks like the one below:

```
  <div class="rTable">
     <div class="rTableRowS">
        <div class="hCell">SIT</div>
     </div>
     <div class="rTableRowS">
        <div class="rTableCellS">Header 1</div>
        <div class="rTableCellS">Header 2</div>
        <div class="rTableCellS">Header 3</div>
        <div class="rTableCellS">Header 4</div>
     </div>
     <div class="rTableRowQ">
        <div class="rTableCellQ">a1</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">single</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">a2</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">secondary</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">a3</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">single</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">a4</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">secondary</div>
     </div>
     <div class="rTableRowS">
        <div class="rTableCellS">header 5</div>
        <div class="rTableCellS">header 6</div>
        <div class="rTableCellS">header 7</div>
        <div class="rTableCellS">header 8</div>
     </div>
     <div class="rTableRowQ">
        <div class="rTableCellQ">b5</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">single</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">b6</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">secondary</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">b7</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">single</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">b8</div>
        <div class="rTableCellQ">secondary</div>
     </div>
```

Desired output (look and feel):

```
SIT
Header 1    ¦ Header 2       ¦ Header 3         ¦ Header 4
a1 ¦ single ¦ a2 ¦ secondary ¦ a3 ¦ single ¦ a4 ¦ secondary 
Header 5    ¦ Header 6       ¦ Header 7         ¦ Header 8
b5 ¦ single ¦ b6 ¦ secondary ¦ b7 ¦ single ¦ b8 ¦ secondary
```

and so on.

What is an easy XSLT1.0 transformation to achieve the column matching (based on div). I can adapt the input XML to some level, such as changing the class entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using divs with nested display=table entries: a row contains cell which contain a table again.